# How can I add a css file into my TinyMCE template?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

My question is about Tinymce Template Plugin.

I have been developing a CMS with ASP.NET MVC. I can insert a template by using “insert template plugin”, but I can not insert a css file.

The template I will insert should be more developed. When I add a css file, it does not work. For example, `<link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“theme.css”>`. This link is my template I want to use.

And then I am saving this content into my database. This link can not be saved into my database. It can not be seen.

I used content_css ,the template looks good in the editor, but when I look at the page, it looks very bad because the css files does not work. In addition to all of these, when I look at the table of database (column : content) there are not css links (`<link href...`)

What should I do for this problem ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS links belong in the head of the document, it is not valid HTML to add the link tag to the body.  The Template Plugin allows you to add fairly involved HTML to the HTML *body* so you don't have to build that chunk of HTML over and over again. Please read the documentation for Templates: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/template/

When you apply CSS in content_CSS it only affects how TinyMCE looks in the iFrame that the editor lives in. You need to get the CSS into the head of the page you are bringing over from your databse.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much, sir.